# TypeError (null reference exception) when using dom-construct.place

Tags: javascript, dojo

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null
>   {stack: (...), message: "Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null"}

Encountered the above error in the following line after upgrading dojo. Does anyone knows how I can fix it, or should I report it as a bug?

```
require([..., "dojo/dom-construct"], function(..., domConstruct) {
    //some code
    domConstruct.place(legPic, curLayer.id + '_chkBox_' + curLegLyr.layerId, "after");
});
```

Comment: "upgrading dojo" from what version to what version?

Comment: Upgraded from 1.2 to 1.10

Comment: Wow that is a big upgrade, you should debug that line and be sure that legpic is a node, and that the concatenated id is valid.

Comment: I've already tested them all, they are all valid

Comment: If you can setup a jsfiddle showing the failure I can take a look.  http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2014/10/15/dojo-faq-how-to-use-jsfiddle-to-provide-a-functioning-test-case/

Comment: But the code is huge, and there might be some not ready modules when this part is executed even if I call `ready(function(){...})` I'll try to come up with a sample code though, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curLayer.id + '_chkBox_' + curLegLyr.layerId` is likely referencing an ID that does not actually exist in your document at the time of your `domConstruct.place` call.

(The error corresponds to [this line](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/1.10.4/dom-construct.js#L188) in the Dojo source.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually there's been a `token` issue earlier in my code, and I think since it didn't have access to that layer's id, it was returned as null